# EF 6 and EF Core

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two applications:

1. WCF service using EF6
2. Web API server, planning to use EF Core

If they both connect to the same database, are there any compatibility concerns in terms of schema generation or anything regarding data integrity?

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features).  Especially if you use Code First.  Personally, the lack of support for complex/ value types is a non-starter.  If it were me, just stick with EF6.  EF core is just not ready for prime time unless you have very basic needs.  You can also use .net core web api with EF6.

Answer (score 1):

It depends: We are currently in a similar situation, where our production systems run EF 6, and we plan to use EF Core in the future. So far we have one smaller application running EF Core on the same database without any problems, but you have to consider some things for your situation:

- EF Core does not yet support all of the EF 6 features (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features), so check if there are any no-gos for you
- You can map EF Core to only a subset of the tables mapped in EF 6, and by doing so you avoid problems with tables that use unsupported things like TPC, complex types, ...
- Keep your code-based migrations in EF 6 until everything you need is supported in EF Core

Answer (score 1):

EF 6 and EF Core are just ORM's. They will not interfere with each other when reading and writing to a database.

As noted by others you may get in trouble if you are doing a code first strategy.

Answer (score -2):

It Depend. Entity Framework Core (EF Core) is a lightweight, extensible, and cross-platform version of Entity Framework  [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features)

EF 6 only work in .net framework,
if you planing to run your API in Cross-platform  User EF Core